# Notification is removed from status bar when I close the app

Tags: android, notifications

I send a simple notification to the user when they open the app. When I swipe the notification away from the status bar, the notification is also deleted.

I just want the notification to stay on the status bar even if I close the app like whats app Instagram and some other apps.

This is how I send notification

```
 Context context = getActivity();

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, 0);


    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setTicker("Notification")
            .setContentTitle("Important Message")
            .setContentText("This is an example of a push notification using a Navigation Manager")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);



    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    //These are necessary for the notification to pop up
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(alarmSound);
        builder.setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500);
    }

    //after android O we must use notification channels
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        String channelId = "Your_channel_id";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Reminder to remind to review your notes",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);


        channel.setDescription("Hello Dear friends"); //this is to test what this is

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        builder.setChannelId(channelId);
    }


    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;



    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

P.S1: I don't want the notification to persist like in foreground services. I just want to not go away when the app is swiped away, but the user can get rid of the notification anytime they want.

P.S2: I am not using any services, just a simple notification. Like e.g.letting the user know that they collected some badges today.

Comment: Hi there, Which device are you testing on?

Comment: Xiaomi redmi note 8. It works fine if I first minimize the app and the swipe it away. but If I'm in the app and swipe it away, notification also goes away.

Comment: Can you verify if the same is happening on other devices?

Comment: I tested on emulator which is API24 and there is no such problem

Comment: Yes I once had a colleague rage all about notifications only to find out in the end that it was some issue with Huawei devices. 
So your issue is not really an issue but OEM specific feature. Maybe there is something in the Settings to toggle it on/off, maybe there is not. But that is how the android ecosystem is. OEMs do their own stuffs :D

Comment: I understand, but there are apps like whatsapp that don't have such problems on same device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219556/discussion-between-ravi-and-keivan-k).